# Tensorflow.js TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'texShape[0]')

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, tensorflow.js

I am trying real-time detection using my custom model using tensorflow.js in expo.

I saw that post and changed my yoloV5 model to json format.
(using tensorflowjs_wizard)

When I run myCustomModel.executeAsync(tensor), it returns the error "[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'texShape[0]')]".

input tensor:

```
Tensor {
  "dataId": Object {
    "id": 451,
  },
  "dtype": "float32",
  "id": 454,
  "isDisposedInternal": false,
  "kept": false,
  "rankType": "4",
  "scopeId": 2,
  "shape": Array [
    1,
    320,
    320,
    3,
  ],
  "size": 307200,
  "strides": Array [
    307200,
    960,
    3,
  ],
}
```

code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, Image } from "react-native";
import { ThemeColor } from "../../theme/ThemeColor";
import "@tensorflow/tfjs";
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
import * as DocumentPicker from "expo-document-picker";
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";

import { Camera } from "expo-camera";
import { bundleResourceIO, cameraWithTensors } from "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native";

const TensorCamera = cameraWithTensors(Camera);
const threshold = 0.75;


export default function RealTimeDetection({ navigation }) {
    const expoCamera = useRef();
    const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
    const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);

    const [predictResult, setPredictResult] = useState([]);

    const [frameworkReady, setFrameworkReady] = useState(false);
    const [cocoSSDModel, setCocoSSDModel] = useState(null);
    const [textureDims, setTextureDims] = useState({
        height: 0,
        width: 0,
    });
    const [tensorDims, setTensorDims] = useState({
        height: 0,
        width: 0,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const screen = Dimensions.get("screen");
        (async () => {
            const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
            setHasPermission(status === "granted");

            await tf.ready();

            console.log(tf.getBackend()); // return "rn-webgl"

            setCocoSSDModel(await loadCocoSSDModel());


            setFrameworkReady(true);
        })();

        if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
            setTextureDims({
                height: 1920,
                width: 1080,
            });
            setTensorDims({
                height: Math.floor(screen.height) - 100,
                width: Math.floor(screen.width),
            });
        } else {
            setTextureDims({
                height: 1200,
                width: 1600,
            });
            setTensorDims({
                height: 1100,
                width: 800,
            });
        }

        return () => {
            tf.disposeVariables();
            setFrameworkReady(false);
            setPredictResult([]);
        };
    }, []);

    const loadCocoSSDModel = async () => {
        try {
            console.log("model load");


            const modelJSON = await require("../../assets/models/model.json");
            const modelBin = await require("../../assets/models/group1-shard.bin");
            const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, modelBin));

            console.log("success!!");
            return model;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("error: ", e);
            alert("model load failed");
            navigation.navigate("Home");
            return;
        }
    };

    const handleCameraStream = (images, updatePreview, gl) => {
        const loop = async () => {
            const nextImageTensor = await images.next().value;

            await getPrediction(data);

            // if autorender is false you need the following two lines.
            updatePreview();
            gl.endFrameEXP();
            requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        };
        if (frameworkReady) {
            loop();
        }
    };


    const getPrediction = async (tensor) => {
        if (!tensor) {
            return;
        }

        console.log(tensor);

        const prediction = await cocoSSDModel.executeAsync(tensor);

        console.log("result: ", prediction);

 
    };

    if (hasPermission === null) {
        return <View />;
    }
    if (hasPermission === false) {
        return <Text>no camera access</Text>;
    }
    return (
        <>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {frameworkReady ? (
                    <TensorCamera
                        ref={expoCamera}
                        style={styles.camera}
                        type={type}
                        zoom={0}
                        cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
                        cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
                        resizeHeight={320}
                        resizeWidth={320}
                        resizeDepth={3}
                        onReady={handleCameraStream}
                        autorender={false}
                    />
                ) : (
                    <Text style={{ color: "#fff" }}>loading . . .</Text>
                )}
            </View>
            <View style={styles.bboxContainer}>
                {predictResult.length > 0 &&
                    predictResult.map((result, index) => {
                        return (
                            <View style={{ position: "absolute", top: result.y, right: result.x, width: result.width, height: result.height, borderColor: colorArray[index], borderWidth: 3 }}>
                                <Text style={{ color: "blue", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                                    {/* {result.class}:{Math.round(result.score * 100) / 100} */}
                                    {result.score}
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        );
                    })}
            </View>
        </>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: ThemeColor.mainColor,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        position: "relative",
    },
    camera: {
        position: "absolute",
        zIndex: 1,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "black",
        borderRadius: 0,
        // zIndex: -1,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
    },
    bboxContainer: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
        position: "absolute",
        zIndex: 99,
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
    },
});
```

Anyone has any idea? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What does the console.log for tensor and prediction indicate ?

Comment: The tensor value is the "input tensor" in the post.
cocoSSDModel.executeAsync(tensor) is throw this error. so prediction is not visible.

Comment: Put the code in a codesandbox to make it easier to debug. Could you try `const prediction = await cocoSSDModel.executeAsync(tensor, ['detection_classes']);` when making predictions?

Comment: Also you do not need to render the camera when the `frameworkReady` is true and you do not need to set `setFrameworkReady(false);` in the cleanup function of the `useEffect()`, the cleanup function runs whenever there are new values in the dependency list but you have none so `frameworkReady` will be false.

Comment: `const prediction = await cocoSSDModel.executeAsync(tensor, ['detection_classes']);` is throw this error (`[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: The output 'detection_classes' is not found in the graph]`).

Comment: @dp_bell link a codesandbox instead then.